Eigenvalues of the product of a stochastic matrix and a doubly stochastic matrix
I am playing with compositions of finite state Markov chains and have this product matrix $P=AB$, where  $A$ is a stochastic matrix (rows sum to 1) and $B$ is a doubly stochastic matrix. Moreover, $B$ is symmetric and block diagonal (each block has same values). For example,
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1/n_1,& 1/n_1,& 0,& 0,& 0,& 0\\
1/n_1,& 1/n_1,& 0,& 0,& 0,& 0\\
0,& 0,& 1/n_2,& 1/n_2,& 1/n_2,& 0\\
0,& 0,& 1/n_2, & 1/n_2,& 1/n_2,& 0\\
0,& 0,& 1/n_2, & 1/n_2,& 1/n_2,& 0\\
0,& 0,& 0, & 0,& 0,& 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
for $n_k$, $k =1,2,\dots$ In this example $n_1=2, n_2=3$. The idea of $B$ is to redistributing the weights within each block of states.
My question is, is there anything special I can say about the eigenvalues (more importantly, the second largest eigenvalue) of $P$ that can relate back to eigenvalues of $A$? Except that the largest one will be one ofc...
In my numerical exercises, I couldn't find any connection between the second largest eigenvalues of $A, B$ and $P$ but maybe there's something i've overlooked?

(I don't know how to relate the $2$nd largest eigenvalue, but at least the trivial result below says the average won't be too big.)
If $K$ is the number of blocks in $B$ and $n=\sum_{k=1}^K n_k$,  obviously $P$ has at least $n-K$ zero eigenvalues, since $B$ is a projection matrix with rank $K$.
Let $\lambda_i{(M)}$ denote the $i$th largest (in modulus) eigenvalue of matrix $M$. By Cauchy-Schwarz ineq., $$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^{(P)} \leq \sqrt{K \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i{(A^TA)}}. 
$$
It follows that, by removing zeros and ones,
the average $\bar{\lambda}_{2..K}^{(P)}$ from the $2$nd to the $K$th eigenvalues of $P$ is $$\bar{\lambda}_{2..K}{(P)}\leq \frac{\sqrt{K \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i{(A^TA)}}-1}{K-1}.$$
In case that $A$ is symmetric (and thus also doubly stochastic),
$$\bar{\lambda}_{2..K}{(P)}\leq \frac{\sqrt{K \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2{(A)}}-1}{K-1}.$$

It doesn't really solve my problem but thank you, Zack!
